# Is it possible to run Pokemon Go with English without changing system locale?

Tags: pokemon-go

Recently Pokemon GO updated and shows all users the language agree with the system locale.

My devices (iPhone SE and iPad mini) were set to use Chinese (Traditional) and so now it is not displaying English at all.

However, although I came from China, I live in Australia now and the kids are still learning Chinese from us whilst they can already read English pretty well.

So I wonder if I can make it display English again without having to change my system locale?

Answer (score -1):

1. 您可以用 factory reset
2. 把手机的语言改回中文

do a factory reset on your phone, then you can change the language back to ZH

Comment: Yes I know this option. However, this is NOT what I want! I said "WITHOUT change system locale".